# Attempting to define dual crossover for barrier optimization in CPLEX

Tags: cplex

I am exploring what the tradeoffs are between no crossover, crossover w/ default settings, and crossover with just dual for barrier optimization.

When I attempt to define my solver settings for the crossover with dual, I thought, based on the CPLEX documentation, that I would use the [barcrossalg] parameter and set it equal to 2. however, when I kick off a study, I get an error message back stating only the following parameters are available.

Is "barrier" the actual setting I am looking for and not barcrossalg?

I am using version 20.1.0 of CPLEX community edition.

**Available options reported back to me by the solver:**

`advance, barrier,benders, clocktype, conflict, cpumask, defaults, dettimelimit, distmip, emphasis, feasopt, logfile, lpmethod, mip, multiobjective, network, optimalitytarget, output, parallel,  paramdisplay, preprocessing, qpmethod, randomseed, read, record, sifting, simplex, solutiontype, threads, timelimit, tune, workdir, workmem`

Answer (score 4):

To use the barrier algorithm without crossover with cplex 20.1, you can use the following options:

- set lpmethod 4 (this selects the barrier algorithm):
  [image]
- set solutiontype 2 (this deactivates crossover):
  [image]

The log looks like this:
[image]

You can see the barrier algorithm is indeed used. If you activate crossover, you can view some additional information:
[image]

Comment: thank you but i am able to get barrier w/o crossover. my question is how to do barrier w/ crossover but specifying dual only and not have the default settings, which uses both primal and dual.

Comment: You can refer to: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/20.1.0?topic=parameters-barrier-crossover-algorithm

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the interactive optimizer, you need to type "set barrier crossover" (or just "set barrier" to get a list of available parameters related to the barrier method). When you type "set" to get a list of parameters, "barrier" refers to a submenu, not a single parameter. (Note the explanation: "set parameter**s** for barrier optimization".)

Comment: perfect! thank you for the explanation. i was able to get the setting defined.